# How to find list of missing characters in a column from another column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables. Tab_1.col_2 has characters and Tab2.col_2 has strings

```
Tab_1
col_1   col_2
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       N

Tab_2
col_1   col_2
101     CCNCCN
102     ABCNSN
103     TABGNN
```

I want to be able to search Tab2.col_2 using Tab_1.col_2 and identify all the missing characters

There is no join condition available between these two table. I tried to substring each character on Tab_2.col_2 and then do a simple not in function.

Expected result: 
I expect the output to give two characters that are missing from Tab_1.col_2 - T and G as two rows

```
Output:
T
G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a recursive CTE stripping of leftmost char for leftmost char. The get the distinct set of that chars where the char doesn't exist in the set of single chars.

```
WITH
cte (c, r)
AS
(
SELECT substr(t2.col_2, 1, 1) c,
       substr(t2.col_2, 2, length(t2.col_2) - 1) r
       FROM tab_2 t2
UNION ALL
SELECT substr(c.r, 1, 1) c,
       substr(c.r, 2, length(c.r) - 1) r
       FROM cte c
       WHERE substr(c.r, 1, 1) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.c
       FROM cte c
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM tab_1 t1
                                WHERE t1.col_2 = c.c);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a06c9405d609a96b9a6d207f5ff07480)

Maybe you can combine the idea of Gordon removing the existing chars with `translate()` first with the idea of stripping off the leftmost chars one by one to even get a shortcut without the need of the `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

This is only half an answer.

You can remove the unwanted characters by using `translate()`

```
select translate(t2.col_2, rem || ' ', ' ')
from (select listagg(col_2, '') within group (order by col_2) as rem
      from table_1
     ) t cross join
     table_2 t2;
```

You can even aggregate these back together:

```
select listagg(translate(t2.col_2, rem || ' ', ' '), '') within group (order by rem)
from (select listagg(col_2, '') within group (order by col_2) as rem
      from table_1
     ) t cross join
     table_2 t2;
```